# Component position HTML5

Tags: html, sencha-touch-2, mobile-application

Does anyone have any idea if there is a best trick in HTML5 that allows me to make my multi-language app **with changing the position of form components** on HTML5 (special case for the Arabic language)?

Comment: Do you mean [text `direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction)?

Comment: @robertc: I think the question is about switching the place of label and field.

Answer (score 0):

With Sencha Touch, you can switch the place of label and field with the [labelAlign property](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.field.Text-cfg-labelAlign). By default, the label of a field is displayed to the left but you can define 'right' to push it to the right.

Here an example with a text field:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    label: 'First Name',
    name: 'firstName',
    labelAlign: 'right'
}
```